# Can Spring Data Rest provide enough flexibility to be used in real world applications?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm just starting with Spring Boot (I have experience with Java EE). I need to develop a RESTful API. I've read this tutorial about Spring Boot https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

I found it very interesting, because there is no overhead for creating a Service layer, a Resource layer, it's all done by Spring automatically. On the other side, I'm not sure if it can provide enough flexibility: where does business logic go? Or is Spring Data suitable only for simple CRUD applications?

Comment: Can someone please tell me what's so bad about my question, and why it got 4 down votes in just 10 minutes?

Comment: One major problem with your question (but this is should not been a valid reason for a downvote) is, that one an superficial thinking about it, it looks as an primary opinion based question. But if one spend more time in thinking and writing an answer more than just "yes/no" it is clear that it is not opinion based.. So I hope my answer is based on facts and helps you.

Comment: Let me translate it to simple English: "I just read a tutorial, and I'm not sure if this framework is suitable for me. Opinions?" Now it's obviously opinion based or too broad. Unless the documentation states "This should not be used in production code", it's pretty safe to assume that there are no inherent flaws that would prevent its use. Of course you'll need to have enough experience to assess whether it's suitable (or optimal) for *your* use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring-Data-Rest does not prohibit to use server- and controller- layer.

If you have more than a plain simple CRUD backend, then I recommend to have 
- "Controller-Layer"
- Service-Layer
- Respositroy-Layer based on Spring-Data

Maybe you should thinks about allowing that the controller-layer can access the repository-layer directly (for read operations) when there is no business functionality needed.

Comment: Are you saying Spring Data Rest doesn't prohibit it but you recommend not using it for more than a simple CRUD backend?